# How to stop the schedule task in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

In my schedule job, I am calling rest api using rest template. Due to RestTemplate lock my schedule job is running state many days. Is there any way to stop the schedule Job without restarting the APP?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely you cannot unblock that thread unless you can cause it to crash.  Consider removing the machine from the network temporarily (e.g. by pulling a cable or taking the network interface offline) that will sometimes cause a network error, and if your code does not retry, maybe your scheduled job will crash.

Next time consider:

- timeouts on the job
- An HTTP endpoint for you to invoke a kill switch
- ManagementBeans to allow you to invoke a kill switch